# javascript document.forms[0] and document.<formname> have different elements

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I am trying to implement client side validation in Struts 2. my theme is `xhtml`. The javascript generated is not able to validate my code. After debugging , I found that Struts is using the following notation to refer the elements.

```
form = document.getElementById(<form id>);
service = form.elements['service'];
```

the point is that service is coming as `undefined`.
when I checked that `form.elements` is `null`; However if I access form using `document.formname` i am able to see the fields in elements collection.

I am thinking `document.forms[0]` is returning the same object as  `document.getElementById(formid)`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The form element can access fields by name, for this purpose you should get the form element. You can do it in many ways, use `document.getElementById()` or `document.forms[]`, or `$("#formid")`. Whatever way you choose doesn't matter.  Just note that a document can contain many forms, so you should reference a correct one. Getting form element by id returns an element that has an `id` attribute, getting it by the index in the `forms` property you should know the correct index. Once you get the form element you can reference input fields by name. For example

```
<form id="formid">
 <input name="service">
</form>
<script>
 var v = document.getElementById("formid")['service'];
</script>
```